# Livewire and RateYo but when reloading Livewire, RateYo does not update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, rateyo

I use LiveWire to display ratings from users but have a problem: when I switch to another page, the rating data is updated but RateYo is not displayed. I have created a listening event every time the livewire reloads, but it doesn't reload RateYo to display as I expected. Below is my code. Please help me, I thank you

Code for display data rating

```
<div>
    <div class="border shadow p-2 mt-4 gap-2 table-data" style="height: 600px;">
        @foreach ($listRating as $index => $listRatings)
            <div class="pb-2">
                <p class="dynamic-content">{{ $listRatings->name }} and {{ $listRatings->place_ratings }}</p>
                <div class="listRateYo" data-rating="{{ $listRatings->place_ratings }}"></div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        <div id="pagination-links" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            {{ $listRating->appends(request()->all())->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for uses RateYo

```
<div wire:ignore>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function() {
            $(".listRateYo").each(function() {

                var ratingValue = $(this).data("rating");
                console.log(ratingValue);

                $(this).rateYo({
                    starWidth: "20px",
                    rating: ratingValue,
                    fullStar: true,
                    readOnly: true,
                }).addClass('rateyo-set');
                console.log("RateYo is being called for:", this);
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```